# .htaccess constantly broken

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am having serious problem with one of my clients - their website is constantly getting Internal Server Error . I found out that problem is with .htaccess file.
Something is breaking .htacess syntax and form .
For example, last time i opened .htacess there were two blank rows at beginning. Before that, two weeks, something added character "s" t the end of file and broke it.
Can it by by some plugin or wordpress core, or maybe somebody is having an acess to modifying that file.
We didn't give access to anybody to ftp.

Comment: check permission of .htaccess file and set it accordingly.

Comment: I bet a plugin is making changes to it. You can keep .htaccess from being modified by wordpress but you would have to manually make changes to it whenever you do an update. Check the ownership of the file and make it your ftp user. then wordpress won't be able to modify it.

Comment: how to do it. When i try to change 644 to 444 in permissions its constantly rolling back to 644.
How can i prevent plugins doesnt rewrite that?